# Fetching User by Id does not return

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have made a successful connection to Azure AD (at least I hope so, unable to tell the details), and now I am trying to get some user's details. But the step-through debugger does not proceed over the following line:

```
IUser result = azureDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(someId).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

That I got until here, no error is thrown and the function does not return - what does that tell me? How can I debug the issue further?

Comment: Where is the code that deals with the async return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to wait for the result somewhere using the **await** Keyword, also specify that the method is **async** so it runs asynchronously

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction()
{
    IUser result = await azureDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(someId).ExecuteAsync();
    return View(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you catch when you debug this:

```
 try
    {
    IUser result = azureDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync().Result;
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
console.white(e.message)
    }
```

How do you connect to Azure AD? Make sure you get the accurate Accesstoken:

```
  public static string GetTokenForApplication()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Constants.AuthString, false);
            // Config for OAuth client credentials 
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(Constants.ClientId, Constants.ClientSecret);
          AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(Constants.ResourceUrl, clientCred);
            string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }
 ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(https://graph.windows.net, TenantId),
                async () => await GetTokenForApplication());
```